# How to collect timing data in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I need to collect data for timings like page load time, page download time I also found parameter for these i.e. plt and pdt respectively but I am not sure on how to send collect call for these through javascript. Can someone please help me

Comment: Google collects much of the data automatically (at least if you use the javascript tracker), although only for a sample of the page visitors (you will find that in the behavior reports). Can you be a bit more specific about your use case (how do you collect the data, is sampled data good enough etc) ?

Comment: how the data is automatically collected as when I see the collect calls I do not found any timing related data in it. Like "page load time"  i,e plt parameter. I see data like page name and title but do not see any thing related to timing. Do i need to send any different event call or with pageview also it is automatically collected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read up where you can find the automatically [collected page speed data here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1205784?hl=en). The page speed report has various metrics that are collected via the [navigation timing API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigation_timing_API). These include basically everything from DNS Lookup time to page load time.

You can also implement [User Timings](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/user-timings),  if you want to report how long it took a user to complete a certain action on your page.

However timing hits are capped at a sample of 10 000 sessions or 1% of your visitor (whatever happens first). You also collect user timings as custom metrics. Simo Ahava has a nice [blog article about this](https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/track-content-engagement-part-2/).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to be more specific timing event is automatically called after each pageview call. But by default sampling is set to 1% so we rarely observe it. So after changing setSiteSpeedSampleRate to 100 timing call are getting recorded.

By setSiteSpeedSampleRate we can change sampling rate